# Javascript Issue, flexslider script not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently had to rebuild a website from web archive. The client web dev disapeared.. Anyways I got everyting working again except the javascript that runs the flexslider.

go to gervee.com to see the side, if you click the arrows it does nothing. The console shows this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined on line 12

here is the code

jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: "slide" });

yet glancing at the javascript files, it appears that there is flexslider code. However Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Not sure what to do next?  You need to include jQuery.  You may have flexslider, but flexslider depends on you having already loaded jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try moveing that line to after the rest of your scripts and then surounding the code with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what gervee.com has currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: "slide" });</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> document.cookie = 'adaptive_image=' + Math.max(screen.width, screen.height) + '; path=/'; </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'>\x3C/script>") </script>
```

It is trying to use jQuery before it is loaded.  Try changing it to this (move flexslider to after jQuery is loaded):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.cookie = 'adaptive_image=' + Math.max(screen.width, screen.height) + '; path=/'; </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'>\x3C/script>") </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: "slide" });</script>
```

Also, I know you are just trying to get this back up and working for them, but ideally you would not want to load scripts in `<head>`.  It would be better to reference them at the bottom of `<body>` and also to use `$(function() { ... })` to execute any javascript on document.ready instead of inline (as LukasGuptaLeary mentioned in his answer).  That makes the page load faster and helps prevent issues with things being used before they are loaded.  Just felt the need to mention this.

Comment: hmm still nothing but I did move it below

Comment: OK.  is the error gone though?  Maybe it is a different issue now

Comment: I took another look at your site. It looks like jQuery is loading, but maybe something is redefining $.  Can you replace this `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: "slide" }); }); </script>` with this `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: "slide" }); }); </script>` and see what happens?